# Highstock table data: navigable with the range selector and the navigator - scrollbar

Tags: highcharts

Anyone had created a table view, not creating a chart from a table, but a pure table grid view using the highstock library?

I need to be able to navigate in time (table grid get updated dynamically, like chart does) using the navigator-scroll-bar and range selector. Basically just replace the chart by a pure HTML table grid of data.

It needs to be done with highstock chart, probably not highchart library, coz I am looking for time navigation component to update the table accordingly to new time range changes...

I guess this could be achieved with callbacks on the navigator and range selector?

Comment: Do you mean something like that? http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table

Comment: I have seen it, unfortunately this a data table for highchart, I'm looking for the same but with a highstock chart, which has the time navigation that does not exist with highchart. I want to be able to navigate in time with highsotck navigator and see the table grid dynamically updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes), get all visible serie's data from chart.series (between min/max values which limit range) and return table in defined i.e div.